# Python File Parser

Tags: python, file, parsing

This is a model of a text file that I want to parse:

```
Something: different

Date: 22:23:32
```

I want to get the information after the `:`, for example: `different` and `22:23:32`.

The only way in which I know how to do it, is to parse each line and split after `:`. The problem is that in case of date, it will crash.

This is the code I have written up to now:

```
for line in file:
    if re.match("Something", line):
        line = line.split(':')
        print (str(line[1]))
    elif re.match("Date", line):
        ???
```

This is just a simple example, the file which I need to parse containing much more information that I need to extract.

Which would be the most efficient way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a limit with `split()`:

```
line = line.split(':', 1)
```

This way, `this:that:somethingelse` is interpreted as `['this', 'that:somethingelse']`.

Answer (score 2):

Use second parameter of split method, it allows you to avoid problem with few `:` in one line, see code below:

```
for line in file:
    data = line.split(':', 1)[1]
    print data
```

> str.split([sep[,maxsplit]])
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus,
>   the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements).

Source: [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Same answer in the same second as mine.

Comment: @zondo we are thinking in same directions ))